# Get the region that user set on Android

Tags: android, kotlin

Is there a way to get the Region that user set on Android phone?
By region I do not mean the region based on locale.
But the region the user set in

**Settings >> Additional Settings >> Region**

For example, a user might set [Locale to en_US] and [Region to Germany]. Via locale I get US, but I want to get DE or Germany. Location manager is out of the question since I still need that region from settings (DE or Germany) even if user / phone is not physically in Germany.

All of the answers I have found provide the idea of getting the region from locale or location manager, but none of the works for task at hand, as I need the exact setting for region, regardless of the locale or the actual location of the phone.

Cheers